# Does variables holding the empty value also occupy the space in ram?

Tags: c, variables, byte, bit, ram

In any programming language if I set the variable:

```
name = 'Jhon';
```

So, it will occupy 4 bytes of space in the RAM. But what if:

```
name = '';
```

It will still hold an empty area in the `RAM` or what will be the scenario?

Comment: By "x" do you mean "C"?

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: there is no good answer to your question. All languages are different. All languages have some optimizations which can remove the var all together. some require additional metadata for variables itself. For 'c', if it is not optimized, the first example will occupy 5 bytes, the second, 1 byte. It might be word-aligned.

Comment: Which language? Which memory? If you don't use the variable compiler can strip it. 'John' is a string I suppose (not in C/C++, looks like you are using PHP). Strings are base types in many languages but the memory occupation depends. Some languages store strings with length prefixes, some with termination (like C), some with range of memory. Alignment can also affects memory requirement. Some implement some smart copy so for instance copying a constant string (like you did in your example) can take just a pointer.

Please be more specific!

Comment: What will be the scenario in `Javascript`?

Comment: If you want to know about Javascript then you should pose a question about Javascript.  You have sent mixed signals by tagging [c] yet presenting prose suggesting that you want an all-language-encompassing answer, and now asking about Javascript in comments.  Read according to the prose alone, this question is far too broad.  Taking into account the tag and comment, it is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is assuming that the code is in C, and that the variable isn't simply optimized out of existence:

Since this is tagged C, I assume `name` is of type `char *`, or pointer to `char`. This means that the variable `name` itself will always take either 4 (32-bit systems) or 8 bytes (64-bit systems), as that is how big a pointer typically is.

The amount of memory pointed to by `name`, however, will vary as you described with one caveat - you need to add one extra byte for the terminating character. This character is a special character that indicates to the program that the string is finished.

With both of the above, `char * name = "Jhon";` actually requires 13 bytes of space - 8 bytes for the pointer, 4 bytes for each of the characters, and another byte for the terminating character. Similarly, `char * name = "";` requires 9 bytes of space - 8 bytes for the pointer, and one byte for the terminating character.

Comment: Use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`. The meaning and syntax are very different.

Comment: What will be the scenario in `Javascript`?

Comment: @PurpleBytes: If you are interested in JavaScript, then I recommend that you ask a separate question and indicate (both via tagging the question appropriately and in the body of the question itself) that you are interested in how this occurs in JavaScript specifically. As it is, you have tagged the question with `C`, hence the answers related to the C programming language. Please don't simply edit your current question, as edits that invalidate existing answers (both mine and John's) are typically frowned upon.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to C, a compiler is allowed to not set aside storage if that storage isn't necessary to implement the *observable behavior* of a program.  For example, if you have a program like

```
int main( void )
{
  int x;
  int y;

  y = some_value();
  printf( "y = %d\n", y );
  return 0;
}
```

the variable `x` is never referenced, and plays no role in the computation or display of `y` (we're assuming it's not visible to `some_value()`).  In this case, the compiler is free to not set aside any space for it.

Similarly, in a program like

```
int main( void )
{
  int y = 0;
  printf( "y = %d\n", y );
  return 0;
}
```

the compiler can determine that this is exactly the same as writing

```
int main( void )
{
  printf( "y = 0\n" );
  return 0;
}
```

and not bother setting aside space for `y` at all.

Different languages have different rules; if you're curious, ask about that specific language.